# How to implement Vaughn Vernon's recommendation in DDD about references in aggregates

Tags: jpa, domain-driven-design, spring-data-jpa

Following Vaughn Vernon recommendation in DDD about references in aggregates

> Let aggregates reference other aggregates by ID (identity), not the aggregate itself.

How to acomplish this with JPA and Hibernate 4.3.11.Final?

I try to use [this  example](http://lorenzo-dee.blogspot.com.co/2013/05/domain-driven-design-referencing.html?showComment=1461665687721#c4672445720415772340):

Something like

```
@Entity
public class OrdenItem implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Orden.class, optional = false)
    private Long ordenId;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Product.class, optional = false)
    private Long productId;
    .
    .
    .
```

But when I try to retrieve some instance with Spring Data

```
@Query("" 
        + " SELECT b " 
        + " FROM  OrdenItem b "
        )
List<OrdenItem> findByYYYY();
```

The following error appears

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set java.lang.Long field com.aggregates.model.OrdenItem.ordenId to com.aggregates.model.Orden
>   at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:167) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
>   at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:171) ~[na:1.8.0_51]
>   at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:81) ~[na:1.8.0_51]

I know that this works if I change the code to

```
@ManyToOne
private Orden orden;

@ManyToOne
private Product product;
```

But  I want to follow Vaughn Vernon's recommendation

Comment: A Long is not a relation, end of. JPA does not and likely will never support using some arbitrary Long as representing an object of some entity type. Bad idea, and not O-O. Specifying ManyToOne on a Long is utterly wrong.

Comment: Thank you Neil, but please give me your feedback in the context of Vaughn Vernon's recommendation. http://dddcommunity.org/wp-content/uploads/files/pdf_articles/Vernon_2011_2.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get ride of the

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Product.class, optional = false)
```

and persist the orderId and productId as numbers in the table.

```
@Column(name="PRODUCT_ID")
```

and that's it.

If you want to get the order with its items and then to get a String representation you would need the product names, and that's where I think you want to retrieve products for every order item. 
Allow me to say that this is what Vaughn would do: 
First of all I don't need at all to hold a reference from OrderItem to Order by its identifier orderId so you can remove it safely. From the domain service all you would be doing is just retrieving the order aggregate root with its collections of items aggregated. Instead of making each item to hold a productId, I would change it to make each orderItem to hold another conceptual identity of what I product is and it must be the product SKU or something and you could keep also its name just as it's an order in the real world. Anyways, those values doesn't change at all, are immutable.

Sebastian.

Comment: I'm agree with you, and thanks for recommendation about remove orderid from ordeitem, I think orderitem should be a value object instead entity. I'll keep product Id and a copy of sku and other data of products. You know if is possible that JPA auto generate a foreign key without @manytoone anotation?

Comment: Just forget about the foreign key, you can even forget about holding the productId and still have the conceptual identity through the product SKU, so no foreign keys